# How to put this on code https://graph.facebook.com/ql?q=http://google.com

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api

(PLEASE DON'T CLICK NEGATIVE/DOWN RATE. I NEED ANSWER TO THIS. THANK YOU)

Im very new in coding + learning i wanted to edit the code that i have in my site this code/link `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=http://google.com` was already deprecated. However, i found new updated code/link which is `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com`

Now here is the code the requires editing:

```
public function getFacebookData($domain)
        {
            try
            {
                $callback_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?";
                $data = array(
                    'q' => "SELECT comment_count, like_count, share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='$domain'"
                );
```

`$curl_response = $this->curl->get($callback_url . http_build_query($data, '', '&'));

            if ($curl_response->headers['Status-Code'] == "200") {

                $parse_response = json_decode($curl_response, true);
                $fb_share_count = $parse_response['data'][0]['share_count'];
                $fb_like_count = $parse_response['data'][0]['like_count'];
                $fb_comment_count = $parse_response['data'][0]['comment_count'];

            } else {
                $fb_share_count = 0;
                $fb_like_count = 0;
                $fb_comment_count = 0;
            }

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'data' => array(
                    'fb_share_count' => filter_var($fb_share_count, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
                    'fb_like_count' => filter_var($fb_like_count, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
                    'fb_comment_count' => filter_var($fb_comment_count, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
                )
            );

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        return $response;
    }`

Comment: "new to learning" lol. But welcome to SO! Please post a question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but regarding the issues - i dont know which part is the problem as its look like the code is clean `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com` is working only in the browser but not in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change your callback_url in code to**

$callback_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?"

Comment: shashi how to put it in the code please? The reason is if i use `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/google.com` - then error so i need to add `http://` on `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/http://google.com` then no error. my request is how to put it to my code. Thanks

Comment: shashi Is this Correct: 

    $callback_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?";
         $data = array(
       'id' => "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count FROM link_stat 
         WHERE url='$domain'"
    );

Comment: from that CODE the result will be: `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com` correct right